# How do I force OCaml to inline a function?

Tags: ocaml, inline-functions

Is it possible to tell the OCaml compiler to inline a function, instead of hoping that its optimization process will do so itself?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can both add an attribute to always inline a function

```
let f x = x [@@inline always]
(* which is equivalent to *)
let f x = x [@@inline]
```

or force a specific call to be inlined with another attribute

```
let a = (f[@inlined]) 1
```

If you want to check inlining decisions made by flambda, you can use the `inlining-report` flag.

Comment: Thanks, with your answer I was able to find the [relevant section in the manual](https://caml.inria.fr/pub/docs/manual-ocaml/extn.html#sec261).

Comment: I have also seen the form `let[@inline] f x = x` for function inlining (without 'd')

Comment: `let[@inline] f x = x` is  a shorthand for `let f x = x [@@inline]`.

Comment: As of 2022, the relevant part of the manual is now [that one](https://ocaml.org/manual/flambda.html).